# Mongoid identity_map on for web requests but off for background or rake tasks?

Tags: mongoid

Is there a way to have identity_map on for web requests, but off by default in the console or in rake tasks?  This seems to keep tripping me up.

This is for mongoid and rails.

Answer (score 1):

If you move up to mongoid 3.0.0.rc, then the method **using_identity_map** can be overridden to provide what you want.
Caveat emptor.

config/initializers/identity_map.rb

```
module Mongoid
  module UnitOfWork
    def using_identity_map?
      Mongoid.identity_map_enabled? && Threaded.identity_map_enabled? && (! defined? IRB) && ($0 !~ %r{rake})
    end
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'builder', '3.0.0'
gem 'mongoid', '3.0.0.rc'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

Note that the config file for 3.0.0 is significantly different,
and that the default template currently sets up development only
and is missing sections for test and production.

The **using_identity_map** method is not available prior to 3.0.0, e.g., 2.4.10,
where you will have to reset **identity_map_enabled** explicitly via .irbrc or Rakefile.

Comment: @GrayMurakami Thanks for info. I am hesitant to move to 3.0 at the moment, but definitely will check it out. I guess bson_ext is no longer required in 3.0. Moped has its own BSON serialization implemented.